# Eclipse Javascript error that it doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html-table

Hey guys I have an error in my js that Eclipse is not showing me where it is in my line. Do you have an idea what can it be? Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
function createVersionRow(appKey, version, status) {
  var value = (appKey + ';' + version);
  return '<tr id="' + getVersionRowID(appKey, version) + '"><td>' + version + '</td><td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="version"'+ onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);"'></td><td>' + status + '</td></tr>';
}
```

The error is the return.

Here the function getVersionRowID:

```
function getVersionRowID(appKey, version) {
  return 'row-app-version-' + (appKey + '-' + version).replace(/\./g,'-');
}
```

Here is the function changeVersionStatus:

```
function changeVersionStatus(obj) {
var info = $(obj).val().split(";");
loadVersion(info[0], info[1]);
}
```

Can it be when I call on changeVersionStatus?

Comment: What is the error? What is the text of the error message??

Comment: So there are no errors in the console in the browser?

Comment: I build it and now it said unexpected string but I have no idea what is my error

Comment: not sure how you "build it" but where does it point to in the code?

Comment: Oh, why is `"'+ onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);"'` <--- Why is it not in the quotes?

Comment: it point it on the line return in the function createVersionRow

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean by why it's not in the quote? I am kind off new with the javascript :)

Comment: You are building the string wrong....

Comment: Change this to `name="version" onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);"`

Comment: How I can build my string in the good way then?

Comment: @LGSon it works thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are building the string has a bug in it. You have a mismatch of quotes

```
return '<tr id="' + 
       getVersionRowID(appKey, version) + 
       '"><td>' + 
       version + 
       '</td><td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="version"'+ 
       onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);"'></td><td>' <-- error is here
       + status + '</td></tr>';
```

You have a random closing of it, not sure why...

```
return '<tr id="' + 
       getVersionRowID(appKey, version) + 
       '"><td>' + 
       version + 
       '</td><td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="version" onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);"></td><td>' +
       status + '</td></tr>';
```

If you happen to use browsers that support ES6, you would be better off using template literals. (note, not all browsers support the following)

```
var id = getVersionRowID(appKey, version)
return `<tr id="${id}">
         <td>${version}</td>
         <td class="text-center">
           <input type="radio" name="version" onchange="changeVersionStatus(this);">
         </td>
         <td>${status}</td>
       </tr>`
```